# Example to see return value in multithread scenario

Tags: c#

I have a method. I want to return a value not from the main thread but from separate thread. Can you give example of it?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more detail in order to get a useful response.  Including code might help as well.

Comment: My question is simple. I want to know how to return a value in a method on a seperate thred rather than returning it from main thread and I want an example for it.

Comment: Please provide some background. That's a very unusual idea, so we need to know what you're trying to accomplish. Also: what kind of program (winforms, webforms, etc), and what version of .net?

Comment: Winforms C#3.0..and this is just a learning question..so no background..I want to see an example if it is possible to return a value on a thread other than main thread

Comment: I think there are enough answers here that show you examples.

Comment: @Stan: I see no examples of what he wanted because what he wanted is pretty much nonsense, in general.

Comment: It's not that he wants nonsense, it's that he doesn't understand basic threading concepts

Comment: @John: I agree that his question does not make sense logically. But if you read it really fast, it reads like he wants to call the method on a background thread and return a value to the main thread...i hope.. :)

Comment: @Stan: I don't think he understands enough to want a background thread. That's why I was trying to get him to say what he's trying to accomplish. It turns out from his comment he's not trying to accomplish anything. It's just a "learning question".

Comment: thanks Slaks and Stan for supporting newbee..it is learning question and related to background..i did not know how to ask it..iwill be careful next time before disturbing

Comment: @John: I understand your point. I showed him how to easily start a thread and return a result from it. If that's what he wanted, then good. If not, then we can't help him, because we don't know what he wants. But that's what I got from his initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to check out the [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

```
 //set up your BackgroundWorker
 BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();


        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                //process your e.Result
            }
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //do your work here

            e.Result = "testing"; //set the result to any object
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet has an excellent [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) on threading within .net in general. However, if you would like a more specific answer to a more specific problem, please post more details.

EDIT:
To make have methods return in a thread other than the main thread, all you need is a second thread. Everything done in that thread will be method calls and returns in that separate thread. Passing data between threads is a much more complex and trick subject. As a starting point, again I point to Jon Skeet's [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) to get a good base understanding. Beyond that, there are general principles that can be helpful, like [Asynchronous](http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-asynchronous-method/) calls and [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?ppud=4) (also see [here](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/coding/csharp/backgroundworker/))that can be very helpful, but these are only options, there many ways to do this, and how it should be done is very dependent on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked for:

```
class DoSomething
{
string result;
    public void RunAsync()
    {
        var t = new BackgroundWorker();
        t.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            result = string.Empty; // your code goes here instead of string.empty
        };
        t.RunWorkerCompleted += Finished;//BackgroundWorkerFinished(sender, e);
        t.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public void Finished(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //result has been set, now what?


    }
}
```

Once you get that down this becomes more useful:

```
public static void RunAsync(this Action ActionToAsync, Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> FinishedAction)
    {
        var t = new BackgroundWorker();
        t.DoWork += (sender, e) => ActionToAsync();
        t.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => FinishedAction.Invoke(sender,e);//BackgroundWorkerFinished(sender, e);
        t.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: in your first example, you didn't show how to pass a result out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make sense.  A method returns a value directly to the method that called it, on the same thread.

**EDIT**: If you want a method to supply a value to the UI thread on WinForms, you can call the [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) method.  For example,

```
//In some event handler, such as button1_Click:
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    //This code runs on a background thread.
    //In it, you can do something that takes
    //a long time without freezing the UI. If
    //you need to interact with the UI from 
    //the background thread, use the Invoke
    //method, like this:

    var text = (string)Invoke(new Func<string>(() => textBox1.Text));

    //I assume you'd want to do something more meaningful.
    var result = text + Environment.NewLine + new String(text.Reverse().ToArray());

    //To send the result back to the UI thread, call BeginInvoke:
    BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {
        //This code is back on the UI thread,
        //but it can still use the variables
        //defined earlier.
        label1.Text = result;
    });
});
```

Comment: his question makes sense. he wants to run a method on a separate thread and return a result after it is done running, i don't think his question asked anything about updating the UI.

Comment: What for?  If he's blocking his thread, there wouldn't be any point

Comment: who said anything about blocking the thread? I am confused about why everyone is so confused by this question. You start a thread asynchronously and return the value once its done...

Answer (score 0):

In order for your method to return something from another thread, that other thread must "have" the something, and must indicate that the "something" is ready to be returned. There is no general case of this, but there are specific cases. For instance, a producer/consumer problem where your other thread produces something and puts it into a queue, and the first thread waits until there's something in the queue, takes it out, then returns it.

Another case that makes a little sense is seen in asynchronous ASP.NET pages. The page starts its life normally, issues one or more asynchronous operations, and then returns back to ASP.NET. It does nothing else until all the asynchronous operations have completed. Then, ASP.NET calls a method in the page that retrieves the results of these operation and uses them in the rest of the page.

You may be able to see that these two cases are very different. That's because you seem to have asked a "learning" question that amounts to "I wonder if a method always has to get its return value from the same thread?" But that's not something you ever have to do in real life, not really.

I will add that the Ada programming language includes something like this - someone who's actually *used* it will have to say whether it was useful. If I recall correctly, one task can *rendezvous* with another, and pass data between them.